# Rails and Django migrations on a shared database

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it bad practice to have Django perform migrations on a predominantly Rails web app?

We have a RoR app and have moved a few of the requirements out to Python. One of the devs here has suggested creating some of the latest database migration using Django and my gut says this is a bad idea.

I haven't found any solid statements one way or the other after scouring the web and am hoping someone can provide some facts of why this is crazy (or why I should keep calm).

database: Postgres
hosting: heroku
skills level: junior

Comment: I would suggest you should try migrations only from one of the primary app. Either from django or from rails. It should not be a problem, but for better management purpose, go with only one of the app.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to maintain migrations at one system (in this case, Rails), because it will be difficult to check migrations between two different apps. What you'll do if you'll haven't access to another app?

But you can store something like `db/schema.rb` for django tracked in git.